helmfile template converted to scientific
When using helm template, the rendered result is correct, but when using helmfile template, the namespace is incorrect and displayed in scientific notation. I have already used the quote function in the Helm template file to convert pure numbers. I need help.


you can run "helmfile --debug template" commands to compare outputs and ensure the namespace rendering is consistent

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.  Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve]?  That at least needs to include your Helm chart templates/*.yaml file; if it behaves differently in Helmfile, a relevant fragment from the helmfile.yaml will be helpful as well.
